# jquery variable multi selectors

Tags: jquery

I would like to set a variable that store the length of all checked checkbox that has the class 'checkbox-guest'
seems my code is not working

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]:checked', '.checkbox-guest').length;
```

html : list of input to be checked by user

```
<input type="checkbox" name="guestCheck[]" id="guestCheck'. $index .'"  class="form-check-input checkbox-guest">
```

Comment: Your selector is looking for `$('input[type="checkbox"]:checked' elements inside of the ("context") of `'.checkbox-guest')` element(s), which didn't seem to be what you want? But without your "*[mcve]*"HTML, your selector is impossible to correct without making guesses.

Comment: Please add the appropriate html and the expected result to your question.

Comment: i have to move class 'checkbox-guest' from input to parent element to correct my code. Thank you @David Thomas

Answer (score 0):

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]:checked, .checkbox-guest').length;
```

Try that? Let me know if that works!

Comment: this is given the length to whitout filetring checked checkboxes

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$("input:checkbox.checkbox-guest").length;
```

Comment: this is given the length without adding condition to keep only checked checkboxes